# Find the coordinates of a string in a png image - java

Tags: java, ocr, text-extraction

I need to be able to find the absolute coordinates of a certain String within an png image. The image is a scan of a page of typed text.

I am new to OCR libraries but as far as I can see you can only convert the whole image into plaintext, rather than find the coordinates of a specific word within an image.

Is OCR necessary or am I going about this the wrong way?

Is there any way to find the coordinates of a specific word?

I am using Java - but any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I've done something similar to this before, and my solution was to start at each pixel of the image and see if the it and it's surrounding pixels could form the letters.  We rolled our own OCR though since it was a different situation, so I can't provide any recommendations with typical libraries.

Comment: I am still trying to decide on a library, surely there must be one that does this? If I can't find one though then then checking each pixel seems the best way

Comment: I don't know of any OCR libraries that do this, but there might be some image libraries that do.  When I need to do what you describe I use ImageMagick (not a java solution) http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/ Matching Sub-Images and Shapes